# Guardar archivo dentro de una carpeta compartida de un servido

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

estoy tratando de guardar un archivo en una carpeta conpartida de un servido utilizando este codigo `Archivo.PostedFile.SaveAs(ruta)` me marca un error:

```
El método SaveAs está configurado para que requiera una ruta de acceso raíz y la ruta de acceso '~\\servido\carpeta\archivo.xlsx' no es de raíz
```

me podrian indicar otra funcion para guardar el archivo.

Comment: Puedes convertir una ruta `~/path` a absoluta con `Server.MapPath(ruta)` donde `~/` seria la raiz de tu aplicacion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar haciendo una copia del archivo original a la ruta de la carpeta compartida, pero pues si puedes mostrar mas codigo para ver que es lo que estas intentando guardar por que pues no aclaras que intentas guardar si es un archivo que tu creas o es uno que tomas de otra parte y asi...

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(la ruta de tu archivo))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(la ruta de tu archivo);
        }

    try
  {
     File.Copy(nombre arvhivo, ruta de destino, true);
  }
    catch (IOException ex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Estoy utlizando un FileUpload ese arhcivo que cargo lo quiero guardar en el servidor, como podria obtener la ruta del archivo que estoy cargando? esta ruta seria miruta origen

Comment: estas usando VB o c# y pues la ruta tu la defines y la puedes ver con el explorador de archivos o clik derecho propiedades pestaña seguridad y te da la ruta de tu archivo

Comment: En la pag de microsoft vienen varios ejemplos en ingles y español no se ya los viste??

Comment: No los e visto, pero la ruta no siempre seria la misma por lo cual estoy buiscando una funcion que me encuentre la ruta para poder copiar el archivo al servidor

Comment: Si la ruta no es la misma el nombre del archivo cambiara?? por que hay metodos para buscar rutas pero conociendo el nombre del archivo o la extencion

Comment: Ya lo solucione `Me.fileArchivo.PostedFile.FileName` me da la ruta que necesitaba, gracias por todo (Y)